# yesod install fails

Tags: haskell, yesod

I generally find that cabal install's for more than half of big packages fail, rather a fatal flaw to new users!

This time I am trying to install yesod, any hints?

```
> cabal install yesod
  ...
Loading package time-1.2.0.5 ...

GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
   _get_current_timezone_seconds
whilst processing object file
   C:\Users\guthrie\AppData\Roaming\cabal\time-1.2.0.5\ghc-7.4.1\HStime-1.2.0.5.o
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
     loaded twice.
GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry.

cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
authenticate-1.3.1.1 depends on http-conduit-1.6.1.1 which failed to install.
http-conduit-1.6.1.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
yesod-1.1.1.2 depends on yesod-core-1.1.2.1 which failed to install.
yesod-auth-1.1.1.1 depends on yesod-core-1.1.2.1 which failed to install.
yesod-core-1.1.2.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
yesod-form-1.1.3 depends on yesod-core-1.1.2.1 which failed to install.
yesod-json-1.1.0 depends on yesod-core-1.1.2.1 which failed to install.
yesod-persistent-1.1.0 depends on yesod-core-1.1.2.1 which failed to install.
```

Comment: This is potentially an issue with your version of `cabal` (or perhaps the Windows version of `cabal`). I just ran the installation process successfully from `cabal 1.14.0` from Debian Wheezy.

Comment: C:\Users\me>cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.14.0
using version 1.14.0 of the Cabal library

Answer (score 2):

yesod uses a different version of alex package than the Haskell platform. I always install alex and happy from my distro's package manager apart from ghc and then use cabal. Alternatively, you can always use

```
cabal update && cabal install alex happy
cabal install yesod-platform
```

Answer (score 0):

This most likely occurs due to trying to install with two versions of the time package simultaneously. Can you try running `cabal install yesod-platform` and see if the problem persists?

And as @Inaimathi said, this might be due to an older version of `cabal`. Perhaps also try `cabal update && cabal install cabal-install`.

Comment: Thanks, I did just do the update of cabal-install before this. An install of yesod-platform shows 14 things that will likely be broken, and doing a force-reinstalls fails on "http-conduit-1.6.1 which fails to install", and trying to install it separately says it will likely break another 61 things. Argh. I am not sure if I should continue down this chain of dominoes forcing reinstalls that say they will break so many things??